# Save FFMpeg conversion to PHP variable vs. File System for use with Whisper API?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, openai-api

I just started working on a little demo to transalte audio captured from the front-end as audio/webm using JS and then sent the back-end in a Laravel App.  I guess there are JS libraries that can handle the conversion, but I'd rather use a server side solution with FFMPEG, which I am doing.

The backend code is below. It seems to be working after playing around with the PHP composer package that I'm using vs. one for Laravel that is also there.  I'd rather use this one because I have other PHP apps that are not Laravel.

Questions:

1. With the FFMpeg library, is there a way to capture the converted .mp3 file to a PHP variable in the script rather than saving it to the file system and then reading it back in later ?
2. For the OpenAI call, I'd like to catch exceptions there also.  I just sort of have a placeholder there for now.

   ```
   protected function whisper(Request $request) {

       $yourApiKey = getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY');
       $client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);

       $file = $request->file('file');
       $mimeType = $request->file('file')->getMimeType();
       $audioContents = $file->getContent();

       try {

           FFMpeg::open($file)
           ->export()
           ->toDisk('public')
           ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Mp3)
           ->save('song_converted.mp3');
       }
       catch (EncodingException $exception) {
           $command = $exception->getCommand();
           $errorLog = $exception->getErrorOutput();
       }

       $mp3 = Storage::disk('public')->path('song_converted.mp3');
       try {
       $response = $client->audio()->transcribe([
       'model' => 'whisper-1',
       'file' =>  fopen($mp3, 'r'),
       'response_format' => 'verbose_json',
       ]);
       }
       catch (EncodingException $exception) {
           $command = $exception->getCommand();
           $errorLog = $exception->getErrorOutput();
       }

    echo json_encode($response);

   }
   ```

Comment: I'm sure you know php, being a substrate for scalable web apps, is RAM-limited. You may not know that the web servers behind php (Apache and nginx) are astonishingly efficient at delivering the contents of file system files to web browsers. Those facts should hopefully affect your design. (tl;dr storing mp3 data streams in php variables may not be a great idea.)

Comment: @O.Jones  So just saving the converted file to disk / tmp file location is not a bad solution ?  I usually do use NGINX or OpenResty.  Whisper apparently cannot accept audio/webm, so I need to convert to something else  with FFMPEG (.mp3) and then send that on to the OpenAI API or a local Docker Container running whisper.

Comment: The openAI composer package I am using is this one:  https://github.com/openai-php/client.  There is one for Laravel also, https://github.com/openai-php/laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the stream output of Whisper API directly into a variable. But I think what you meant is you want to:

1. Have the stream response from Whisper stored in memory; or
2. Stored in files that you don't have to manage.

Luckily, the OpenAI client library seems to accept pointer resource (i.e. [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) return variable). The closest thing to that would be to use [php://temp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.memory) read-write stream. PHP would check if the size of it is bigger than 2MB ([configurable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#example-418)), it will create a temp file for storage.

The beauty if this is:

1. If the stream is small, PHP would handle everything with memory.
2. If it is large, you don't have to manage the resulting temp files yourself. PHP would remove the temp file after use.

```php
$mp3 = fopen('php://temp');
$response = $client->audio()->transcribe([
    'model' => 'whisper-1',
    'file' =>  fopen($mp3, 'w+'),
    'response_format' => 'verbose_json',
]);
```

Then you can [rewind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) the `$mp3` stream and read / stream out. For example:

```php
// Move the pointer back to the beginning of the temporary storage.
rewind($mp3);

// Directly copy the stream chunk-by-chunk to the
// output buffer / output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
stream_copy_to_stream($mp3, $output, 1024);
```

With Laravel, you'd probably need something like this:

```php
rewind($mp3);
return response()->stream(fn() => echo stream_get_contents($mp3));
```

Comment: Actually, one question was about saving the FFMpeg conversion to RAM / PHP, instead of saving to disk ?  I am using this composer package:  https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg, but I guess I could also use a different one or just exec ?  Whisper I think currently has a limit on duration of audio clips.  The other question was about catching the specific exception.

I do have it "working" on the net now and just wanting to optimize and build out a controller for OPENAI app.

Comment: @SScotti: [laravel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg) is calling [php-ffmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) for the actual conversion. php-ffmpeg is merely using the command line tool ffmpeg / libav underneath. So the key is if ffmpeg / libav can create any in-memory output.

Comment: ffmpeg uses STDOUT only for debug / development / information outputs. It does not support converting the video / audio directly to STDOUT, and thus stream input into PHP. The closest thing is to convert to unix / tcp / http socket output, in which case ffmpeg will start a long running process for the output. (See [man page](https://manpages.org/ffmpeg).

Comment: I have yet to find way to use either laravel-ffmpeg / php-ffmpeg to trigger that. And even after that, you'd need a way to read that socket correctly from PHP.